# python mathplotlib 3d scatter plot with colorbar ',' marker problem

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, scatter-plot

I've been playing with ray tracing.  I managed to get the plot to have the correct shape and size by using:

ax.set_box_aspect((np.ptp(xs), np.ptp(ys), np.ptp(zs))).

and to have a 4d colorbar plot.

My current problem is with the marker.  Using '.' gives dots as expected

(click images to zoom in)

[image: marker='.']

Changing marker to ',' does not give pixels as expected, but instead gives squares.  Why?

[ While we are here, I tried using my_dpi and figsize=() so the image fills more of the "screen" - without success. ]

[image: marker=',']

Code:

```
filename = "DonInSite_reflection_points.out"


xs = []
ys = []
zs = []
powers = []
phases = []
with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin :
        line = line.replace('\n', ' ')
        line = line.replace(']', ' ')
        line = line.replace('[', ' ')
        line = line.replace(',', ' ')
        words = line.split()
        if len(words) != 5 :
            continue
        xs.append(float(words[0]))
        ys.append(float(words[1]))
        zs.append(float(words[2]))
        powers.append(float(words[3]))
        phases.append(float(words[4]))

print("len(powers) = %d" % (len(powers)))
print("min(powers) = %f" % (min(powers)))
print("max(powers) = %f" % (max(powers)))


import numpy as np
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

my_dpi = 218
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5120/my_dpi, 2880/my_dpi), dpi=218)

#ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.set_box_aspect((np.ptp(xs), np.ptp(ys), np.ptp(zs)))

plt.title("City Hall 3D reflection points scatter plot")
ax.set_xlabel('X-axis', fontweight ='bold') 
ax.set_ylabel('Y-axis', fontweight ='bold') 
ax.set_zlabel('Z-axis', fontweight ='bold')

my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('gnuplot')

yg = ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=np.array(powers), cmap = my_cmap,  marker = ',')
cb = fig.colorbar(yg, ax = ax, label="Power (dBm)", shrink=0.75)

import time
t = time.time()
outfilename = "DonInSite." + str(int(t)) + ".png"
plt.savefig(outfilename, format="png")

plt.show()
```

Comment: We cannot run your code because we do not have your data file, but the problem can be reproduced by replacing 'o' or '^' with ',' in this example: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html

Comment: I can happily provide the data file, but I doubt anyone wants a 23 MB data file (containing 355473 points.). I mhad seen that example, but it has neither the colorbar nor the true shape and size.   But I will  revisit it and try adding the colorbar and true shape and size to it and see if that works. Thanks.

Comment: @RuthC. Now I see.  I have posted an "Issue" on the Matplotlib GitHub page.

Comment: Developers on GitHub have confirmed it as a bug, even for 2D.